# Как снять логи используемых функций вирусной библиотекой dylib в macOS?

Tags: macos, логирование, virustotal

Dylib вирусной программы упакована и зашифрована. Статический анализ чрезвычайно затруднен. Библиотека для запуска использует механизм инжекции в бинарный код зараженной программы. Как выяснить (снять логи) какие функции перехватывает эта библиотека и как их изменяет?

PS Программа препятствует отладке в дебаггере lldb.